# What does the python operator =- do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What does the python operator `=-` do?  I'm not asking about the `-=` operator, which I realize is shorthand for `x = x - value`.

Comment: Have you tested it? Break it down, don't think about it as 1 operator but two: = and -. Thus `x =- x` is negating x as a number.

Comment: @Roberto What do you mean "not valid python syntax"? It's completely valid.

Comment: I could swear there is a dupe for this...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the operator `=-` does not exist. It is only `= (- value)`. So the negative of the value.

Example:

```
>>> x =- 1
>>> x
-1
```

Comment: Yep, `x =- 1` just looks weird.

Answer (score 2):

Why not test it?

```
In [11]: x = 1

In [12]: y = 2

In [13]: y=-x

In [14]: y
Out[14]: -1
```

As you can see it does nothing, but sets a negative value of the variable on the right hand side

Answer (score 1):

There is no `=-` operator. Depending on the context this might be two operators, e.g. `x =- y` is equivalent to `x = (-y)` (so there are two operators: assignment and negation) **or** an assignment with a negative constant: `x =- 1` is equivalent to `x = (-1)` (in this context `-` is not an operator, it's just a negative constant).

Comment: @timgeb https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/918403cfc3304d27e80fb792357f40bb3ba69c4e/Objects/longobject.c#L2137 As you can see `-` is parsed directly, there is no `__neq__` call in case of constants.